# Adding test in JUnit that fails if Serialized Object changes

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, junit

I have the following class that is created with the usage of a builder:

```
public class Foo {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public int getAge() { return age; }

  private Foo(Builder b) {
    name = b.name;
    age = b.age;
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Builder name(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

     public Builder age(int age) {
      this.age = age;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a JUnit test for this where if this class were to change (via new field were to be added, some other changes made to this) that would also be reflected once the class got serialized, I want that test to fail to catch that change. I am not aware of any libraries that can do this, how can this be done?

Comment: Which serialization do you mean? Java Object serialization, json serialization? But in general you would store the serialized data in a file and run a serialization of an instance in your test and compare that to the stored file. Also note that if a field is added to your class but the instances used in the test always have null value for this new field your test might not catch that because your serialization technology might skip null fields totally.

Comment: JSON serialization. The goal of my question was essentially to have a test that would fail if the class that was to be serialized and any changes made to the class.